# Display Many To Many Relationship from Entity Model in ASP.NET GridView Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, many-to-many

Lets say i have two tables: Cars and BodyStyle with a many to many relationship.

In Data Entity Model it would show the two tables but in Sql it has a helper table to link since its a many to many relationship.

I want to know how is it possible to display the all the Styles related to an instance of Car inside a gridview.

so basically the gridview should look like:

ID | Make | Model | Style |
 ----------------------------------'
1 | Acura | EL | Sedan, Luxury|
2 | Acura | MDX | SUV, Luxury|

I cant seem to access the helping table through c#

Sorry I am new to c# programming.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add the helper table into the edm? I would start with adding that or else how would the m know of the existence of the helper table.

Comment: is there a way to add the helper table? if so how?

Answer (score 0):

You got couple of options to do that. Your Car class should have Models Navigation property and your Model class should have Cars navigation property.

First option: Write a stored procedure which will accept the particular (car/model) as a parameter and return back the resultset accordingly and then map that sp in the edm. You can then call the SP from you code-behind (if you are not using Reporsitoy/Separation of Concern) and bind to the gridview.

Second option: If you are having POCO car class, write a Navigation property named Models which will basically query your db (using LINQ to SQL) and get all the models and then You just need to call that property (as IEnumerable) in your UI and bind to gridview.

Hope this helps and hope I have understood your question appropriately